# first row VS Next row VS rownum

Tags: oracle

Those 3 queries return the same result set but use 2 different technics. Is there an advantage using one over the other? The plan and the execution time are in the same cost range.

```
Select * 
from user_tab_columns
order  by   data_length desc,table_name, column_name  
fetch first 5 rows only
```

```
Select * 
from user_tab_columns
order  by  data_length desc,table_name, column_name  
fetch next 5 rows only
```

```
select * 
from (
  Select * 
  from user_tab_columns
  order  by  data_length desc,table_name, column_name  
)  
where  rownum <=5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keywords `first` and `next` as used in the `fetch` clause are perfect substitutes for each other, they can be used interchangeably - this is stated clearly in the documentation. So you really only have two queries there, not three. (The first two are really identical.)

The first query is easier to write and maintain than the last query. On the other hand, it is only available in Oracle 12.1 and later versions; in Oracle 11.2 and earlier, the only option is your last query.

The `fetch` clause is more flexible, for example it allows you to specify `with ties` (to include more than 5 rows if rows with rownum 4, 5, 6 and 7 are tied on the `order by` criteria, for example).