# Is there any difference in Offset Row vs Rows

Tags: sql-server, fetch, offset

In SQL Server is there any difference between Offset Row and Offset Rows in following:

```
Select * From TableName 
Order by Fields
Offset 10 Row;

Select * From TableName 
Order by Fields
Offset 10 Rows;
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [SELECT - ORDER BY Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), in the Arguments section:

> offset_row_count_expression can be a variable, parameter, or constant
>   scalar subquery. When a subquery is used, it cannot reference any
>   columns defined in the outer query scope. That is, it cannot be
>   correlated with the outer query.
>
> **`ROW` and `ROWS` are synonyms and are provided for ANSI compatibility.**
>
> In query execution plans, the offset row count value is displayed in
>   the Offset attribute of the TOP query operator.

Emphasis added.

`ROW` and `ROWS` are identical operators in all but the characters. There are several examples of this in SQL Server; for example `decimal` and `numeric`. Another is that `FIRST` and`NEXT` (for `OFFSET`) are also synonyms.

Often these are to fulfil compatibility or ISO standards.

(*I also would not be surprised if it's a Grammatical "thing". SQL is very "English" in structure, so a statement like `OFFSET 10 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY` isn't very "Englishly". As a result both `ROWS` and `ROW` are permissible as they make grammatical sense.)*

Comment: Same for `fetch next/first` and the `row/rows` in the `fetch` clause: a bit further down the same page: "FIRST and NEXT are synonyms and are provided for ANSI compatibility.

ROW and ROWS are synonyms and are provided for ANSI compatibility."

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding there is no difference in both.

Similarly in oracle, there is no difference in Fetch Next and Fetch First:
[first row VS Next row VS rownum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932080/first-row-vs-next-row-vs-rownum)